# Python submodules not recognized when run in unix

Tags: python, unix, pyspark

I have a python/pyspark project with the following structure:

```
project
     __ini__.py
     module1
           __ini__.py
           file1.py
           file_run1.py
     module2
           __ini.py
           file2.py
           file_run2.py
     shared_allmodules
          __ini__.py
          func1.py
          func2.py
```

File_run1.py:

```
from shared_allmodules import func1, func2
from module1 import file1
```

File2.py:

```
from shared_allmodules import func2
```

I have thia structure in CDSW and it works there. But now i have to move all the files into a unix server and run from there.

But when i run

```
spark2-submit file_run1.py
```

From module1 directory i have an error that "no module named shared_allmodules".

I'm new in python/pyspark and i don't know what i have to do so that my submodules to be recognized in unix.

I don't have a **main**.py because i don't know how to use it.
Also i don't have the condition with if name=main.

My py files have a lot of pyspark code, i just wrote here a part of the directories structure.

Do you know what i have to do in order to run py files in unix that import modules from other directories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the environment variable `PYTHONPATH` which defines visible for the python interpreter directories (ones outside `site-packages`) or install your modules in the system using `setuptools` [[1]](https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/).

Example:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/project:$PYTHONPATH
```

Comment: Can you give me some examples?

Comment: Try the one in the extended reply and tell me whether it works

Comment: Thank you. This worked. But i have a question. So.. if i run the export into a command line and after that i run the python scripts all is good, the subpackages are recognized. But if i deconnect from server and connect again and run the python script i have the same issue- it dont recognieze the subpackages. I have to do this export at every run? Or what should i do in order to keep the env variable for every time a new logg in is made?

Comment: You may add this statement into .bash_profile file on your server. This file must be in your home directory. It  launches all commands in there before start  -good place to set up the environment variables. If you don't have such file - create it. See here more instructions: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/set-environment-variable-linux/

Comment: Another, may be better, way is to install your project system wide. For that, read about pip and python packaging.